# Supabase function not returning data when called from Svelte app

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I've got the following Supabase function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.file_exists(file_path varchar)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  BEGIN 
  RETURN
    (SELECT EXISTS
      (SELECT id
        FROM storage.objects
        WHERE bucket_id='card-pictures'
          AND name=file_path
        LIMIT 1));
  END;
$$;
```

Which I got from here: https://github.com/supabase/storage-api/issues/266

When calling it from the Supabase SQL Editor like this:

```
SELECT * FROM file_exists('test-file.png');
```

I get this result:

[image: table with file_exists column and one row with true]

However when making the following call from my Svelte app:

```
const fileExists = await supabase.rpc("file_exists", { file_path: "test-file.png" });
console.log(fileExists);
```

It's logging no errors but `false` in the data:

[image: error: null, data: false in response]

I've got other functions for searching on multiple other tables, but this is the only one where I don't expect a table as a result, just a boolean, I tried setting the return value to `table (file_exists boolean)` but got an `Invalid SQL query` error

Comment: Do you have any RLS policies on your bucket? E.g. if you don't your and your client uses the ANON key, they won't be able to see the file. See the docs here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/access-control

Comment: @thorwebdev the only policy I have is to allow only authenticated users to INSERT, and my app is using an authenticated session (I check the session is still active).

Comment: You will need to add a read policy as your policy has a select statement.

Comment: @thorwebdev Tried adding read permissions for all users and am still getting false when calling my function